# dirichlet likelihood simplified

Tags: dirichlet-distribution

I am looking for derivation of eqn 5 in C.Moody's paper
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.02019.pdf
where it says the loss function coming from dirichlet enforcement of sparsity is

$L^d=\lambda\sum_{jk}(\alpha-1)logp_{jk}$

When you look up a formal paper, such as https://tminka.github.io/papers/dirichlet/minka-dirichlet.pdf eqn 4

that term is only part of the whole formula. Can someone explain how the Moody is able to eliminate the two Gamma terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation $4$ from Minka's paper is

$$\log P(D|\alpha) = N\log\Gamma\left( \sum_k \alpha_k \right)-N\sum_k\log\Gamma\left(  \alpha_k \right)+N\sum_k (\alpha_k - 1)\log \bar{p_k}$$

If $\alpha$ is fixed and the optimization variables are $\bar{p_k}$, the first two terms are just **constant** and they can be dropped for the purpose of such optimization, after all.

Comment: that was easy, and makes sense.